# How can I unit test servlets with JUnit 4?

Tags: java, unit-testing, servlets, junit

I'm trying to create some JUnit tests for a servlets project.

I found some tools that can assist, such as JUnitEE, Cactus. But these tools use JUnit 3.

Are there any tools for servlet unit testing that use JUnit 4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know JUnitEE but you can try to use HttpUnit http://httpunit.sourceforge.net/index.html for unit testing servlets. Cannot see any reason it would not work with JUnit 4.

Comment: HttpUnit is not a unit test framework, it's for testing running HTTP/HTML sites, and is completely independent of whether servlets are used or not.

Comment: Yes, but Dikla asked about smth to create unit tests using JUnit 4 and not for a unit test framework

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to instantiate an instance of the web server that you are using within your ide.  We used Glassfish to accomplish testing of our EJBs and other non-traditional unit testable features.  It creates a thread that will act as the embedded web server for an execution of a suite of tests.  [code to test in glassfish](http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/embedding_glassfish_v3_in_unit)